# How to retrieve multiple relations with multiple tables in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.8 to build a babysitting site. I have 4 tables with different relationships as below:

[please see this image](https://jaleesa.app/images/StackOverFlow_01_01tabels.png)

The relationships are:

```
Babysitter->hasMany(session)
Sessions->hasOne(Review)
Sessions->hasOne(Kids)
Sessions->hasOne(Babysitter)
Sessions->hasOne(Parent)
```

I want to achieve 2 things:

**First one**

I want to show this result when listing all babysitters. I'm showing this information for each babysitter:

[plsease see this image](https://jaleesa.app/images/StackOverFlow_01_02sitteroverall.png)

See here what I couldn't achieve

[plsease see this image](https://jaleesa.app/images/StackOverFlow_01_04sitteroverall.png)

This is my code

```
Sitters::where('Status', 'active')->where('Verified', 1)->get();
```

**Second one**

Also, I've tried to show kids name with parent review as shown here:

[plsease see this image](https://jaleesa.app/images/StackOverFlow_01_03sitterReview.png)

This is what i'm using

```
Sessions::select('Reviews.*', 'Sessions.Parent_id')->join('Reviews', 'Reviews.Session_id', '=', 'Sessions.id')->with('owner')->where('Trainer_id', session('user')->Id)->where('Status', '=', 'complete')->with('owner')->orderBy('Sessions.id', 'DESC')->get();
```

Here is `Session.php` Model

```
public function owner(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Parents', 'Parent_id');
}
```

Comment: The other way of `HasMany` relation is `belongsTo` not `HasOne`. `Sessions->hasOne(Review)`, 
`Sessions->belongsTo(Kids)`, 
`Sessions->belongsTo(Babysitter)`, 
`Sessions->belongsTo(Parent)`. Try see if this will allow you to query build using the relations.

Comment: Also `Sessions` and `Reviews` can be merged into the same table with `nullable` review's fields. but that's just a preference

Comment: I used both (BelongsTo) and (hasOne) without any luck L(, 5 days now and it seems that I haven't reached to a point. that's why I posted here :(
@N69S

Comment: Is it `sesstion` or `session`? Are those typos? Plus, it's better including relevant parts of your code here than putting inline image links. The links are very distracting.

Comment: it is session, my bad :)  ... I put my code, and the images are to show you what I'm looking for as a final design.

@udo-e

Answer (score 1):

As discussed change the relations:

```
Babysitter->hasMany(sesstion)
Sessions->hasOne(Review)
Sessions->belongsTo(Kids)
Sessions->belongsTo(Babysitter)
Sessions->belongsTo(Parent)
```

**First one**

in `Babysitter.php` declare the following attributes

```php
class Babysitter extends Model
{
    public function reviews()
    {
        $this->hasManyThrough(Review::class, Session::class);
    }

    public function getAverageReviewAttribute()
    {
        return $this->reviews()->avg('Rating');
    }
}
```

Then you just need to call it on the model instance.

```php
$babysitter = Babysitter::first();
return $babysitter->average_review;
```

**Second one**

Just use the relation

```php
$babysitter = BabySitter::with(['sessions' => public function ($session) {
        $session->with(['review','parent','kids']);
    })->where('trainer_id', '=', session('user')->Id) //did not understand this condition
    ->first();
```

This assumes you have `parent`, `kids` and `review` relation declared on `Session::class`. (change the names if needed)

Comment: What is the type of  "declared relations" inside Session::class , hasMany or BelongsTo or ... ?
@n69s

Comment: The Session::class relations are the first thing in my answer

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of searching & testing, this is what worked for me:

Inside (Sitters) Model, put this relation

```
public function sessions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Sessions::class, 'sitter_id')
        ->withCount('reviews')
        ->withCount(['reviews as review_avg' => function($query){
            $query->select(DB::raw('AVG(Rating)'));
        }]);
}
```

Also, inside (Sessions) Model, put this relation

```
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Reviews::class, 'Session_id');
}
```

Now you query like this

```
return $sitters = Sitters::with('sessions')->get();
```

I hope this can help someone :)

Comment: So you are averaging the rating by session and not by Babysitter ?